# When I apply animation on MatDialog in Angular it is not working?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a requirement where I have to open 2 MatDialog on top of another (like clicking on button it should open 1 MatDialog and after clicking button which is on MatDialog another MatDialog should open) but somehow the when apply animation it only apply on first MatDialog. I'm using ngDialogAnimationService package for animation.

Any other way is there to achieve this functionality ?

I'm attaching the link of stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-animation-rpzqsj?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts,app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html,app%2Fhello.html,main.ts,app%2Fdialog-overview-example.css,app%2Fdialog-overview-example.html,material-module.ts